# What do ellipses mean in the context of this Taras Shevchenko poem?

Tags: poetry, ukrainian-language, taras-shevchenko, the-complete-kobzar

I recently encountered the following in a Taras Shevchenko poem (*To Osnovianenko*) in *The Complete Kobzar* (Peter Fedynsky translation):

> Our idea and our song
> Will neither die nor perish...
> And that, good people, is our glory,
> The glory of Ukraine!

What do the ellipses mean here? Normally this would indicate that part of the text was left out, but I can't imagine why they would do that in this context given that this is *The **Complete** Kobzar*.

Answer (score 3):

**Nothing**; all it might do is tell the reader to make a slight pause between the two lines.

The [original 1840](https://www.google.com/books/edition/%D0%9A%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%B7%D0%B0%D1%80_%D0%A2_%D0%A8%D0%B5%D0%B2%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BA%D0%B0/GU5dAAAAcAAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&pg=PA93&printsec=frontcover) punctuation was:

> Не вмре, не загыне:
> Отъ де, люды, наша слава,
> Слава Украины, —
>
> [image]

But [within a few years](https://www.google.com/books/edition/%D0%9A%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%B7%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%8C/PxiW23qc_tQC?hl=en&gbpv=1&pg=PA72&printsec=frontcover) we see the ellipted version. Semantically, it creates a sort of 'double *and*'; recitatively, it tells the reader to wait a beat before saying 'and that'.

It acts as a sort of introductory punctuation that does the same as in this sentence:

> I like to pout, whine, and bat my eyelashes...and that is why I'd make a great toddler.